# Table View Split into comma separated list in Datagrip for columns with "custom" object type

Tags: sql, oracle, datagrip

Here is an example of what I am seeing in DataGrip for columns with the object type that I created with a type of MyObject.

[image: DataGrip Picture Example]

I normally use PLSQL Developer, where each of the items in the comma separated lists you see are split into their own columns based on dot notation for each of the fields in MyObject (UNIT.FirstColumn, UNIT.SecondColumn, UNIT.ThirdColumn) like this:

[image: PLSQL Developer Picture]

I am working on a trial of DataGrip, with hopes of using it full-time, and cannot seem to figure out how to get DataGrip to print out those individual columns like you see in the second picture, rather than comma separated lists.

Has anyone else run into this, and found a way through?

Create Table Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."UNITS" 
   ("UNIT" "TEST"."SPECIAL_UNIT_TYPE" )
```

Also the definition of SPECIAL_UNIT_TYPE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TYPE "TEST"."SPECIAL_UNIT_TYPE" as object
(

  -- Attributes
  name varchar2(200),
  our_ID number,
  their_id varchar2(50)

)
```

Thank you.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question and the SQL query you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I have added the create table statement, and also the SPECIAL_UNIT_TYPE, which is the type of this UNIT column. 

I want data grip to show UNITS.UNIT.NAME, UNITS.UNIT.our_ID, and UNITS.UNIT.their_ID. Instead it shows a list of the three values in brackets.